# Android Deep Link Using Branch SDK

Tags: branch.io

I am using branch sdk for integrating the deep linking in my Android App.

If the app is installed on device, it will redirect to an app along with parameter(Deep Link Data).

If the app is not installed on device, it will redirect to the Playstore page correctly. But after install the app and open it, the parameter wasn't sent into the app.

Is there is any code for this?

Comment: This is probably best handled by their support?

Comment: yes but not sure if i miss something

Comment: We answer programing questions here. Can you provide some code, like how you integrated, or debug output of a first-launch of a first install?

Comment: Aaron from Branch here. It sounds like you have an integration issue here. I'd ask that you compare your setup with this documentation: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#initialize-branch . Feel free to reach out to integrations@branch.io if you have any trouble.